# hping3 - Ignoring not responding ports

Tags: network-scanners, scan

Is there a way to ignore the **not responding ports** in the scan report?

```
james@ahoi:~$ sudo hping3 -q --scan 1-1000 -S 192.168.0.1
Scanning 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1), port 1-1000
1000 ports to scan, use -V to see all the replies
+----+-----------+---------+---+-----+-----+-----+
|port| serv name |  flags  |ttl| id  | win | len |
+----+-----------+---------+---+-----+-----+-----+
  443 https      : .S..A...  64     0  5840    44
All replies received. Done.
Not responding ports: (254 ) (255 ) (439 ) (440 ) (441 ) (442 ) (450 ) (451 ) (458 ) (465 urd) (466 ) (467 ) (468 ) (469 ) (527 ) (549 idfp) (550 ) (551 ) (552 ) (553 ) (739 ) (740 ) (741 ) (748 ) (755 ) (802 ) (803 ) (804 ) (811 ) (812 ) (813 ) (823 ) (934 ) (941 ) (942 ) (943 ) (944 ) (957 ) (958 ) (959 ) (960 ) (961 ) (962 ) (974 ) (986 ) (998 )
```

I tried `-q` but it did not help...

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading this wrong so can you clarify a little... What do you mean by ignore? Do you mean prevent them from appearing during/after the scan?

Comment: Hi @Sevaara. I would like to get them out of the report (after the scan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not the most straightforward, but:

```
hping3 -q --scan 1-1000 -S 192.168.0.1 | grep -v 'Not res'
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine! Is there a native hping3 option?